# Xamarin forms - Customize ContentPage's toolbar item

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, toolbar, custom-renderer

I need to add a label inside a toolbar item in a `ContentPage`.

I would like to create a `CustomRenderer` for iOS, Android and UWP,
but I can't get the toolbar view for each platform.

For example, for Android I have tried to get the `ActionBar` and then add the label, but the `ActionBar` is always null.

How can I create this CustomRenderer?

Thank you :D

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are not using the standard TabbedPage from Xamarin Forms? In general if a class already has a cross-platform implementation in Forms it's harder to make your own custom renderer of it function without weird bugs

Comment: What kind of effect do you want for `ToolBarItems`?.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.toolbaritems?view=xamarin-forms You can show image for different devices?

Comment: Hi, no I need to show a fixed text get from a XML file.

Comment: Adding a sample of your UI requirement would help

Answer (score 1):

Without using renderer:

```
<NavigationPage.TitleView>
  <label text="text"/>
</NavigationPage.TitleView>
```